# Installation of Windows 10 IoT Core on Kontron's ETX LX2 board(Computer-on-Module)

Tags: installation, windows-10-iot-core

I plan to install Windows 10 IoT core on Kontron's ETX LX2 board and as I understand after googling, i have to create .FFU file for the specific device(in my case ETX LX2 board). Microsoft already supports various devices like Raspberry Pi, Intel devices and have .FFU file for them already. I did not find anything for Kontron's ETX LX2 board.

For creation of FFU for the above mentioned device, i need to have the BSP of the device and the Windows IoT Core package bundled together.

Could anyone let me know if my understanding is correct and how to go about creating the .FFU file for the above device?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct. For creation of FFU for device with custom OS, you need to have the BSP which is provided by the board manufacture in genneal and Windows IoT Core default packages. You may refer to [IoT Core manufacturing guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/iot/iot-core-manufacturing-guide).

At the moment, Windows IoT Core does not support ETX LX2. You can find the suggested [rototype boards in this [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/tutorials/quickstarter/prototypeboards).